# Clickhouse Automatically insert data into Summingmergetree from Mergetree

Tags: clickhouse

I am using Clickhouse to store raw data in a MergeTree. I actually need data in a Summingmergetree where columns are summed up based on primary key.

I need to know if clickhouse provides a way where data is inserted automatically into the summinmergetree table as soon as data enters into MergeTree  table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MATERIALIZED VIEW` to achieve that. Support you have a `raw_data` with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_data (key int, i int, j int) engine MergeTree ORDER BY key;
```

Then you can define the `SummingMergeTree` table like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW summing_data (key int, i int, j int) engine SummingMergeTree((i, j)) ORDER BY key AS SELECT * from raw_data;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, if we create Materialized view will not the data in materialized view be deleted if we delete data in Raw_data. How will it affect the summed up data?

Comment: Mutations aren't applied to materialized views. You can delete data in both tables with the same alter command as both use the same key definition.